# Can a Table Lock eliminate a deadlock or make it worse Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-administration, database-deadlocks, table-locking

We have a situation in which an **Oracle Database is having deadlocks issues.**

I said that perhaps we should lock into some table locks, and a guys response to me was

```
  "Unless I am misunderstanding what you mean by a table lock, I don’t think a table lock will eliminate deadlock … it could potentially exacerbate it."
```

Is what he is saying true?

```
--> Error "Deadlock detected while waiting for resource Stack Trace"
```

Here is part of email we get:

```
System Error: Error for Step Type:REMOVE PRED OPEN MAN User Error:       
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource Stack Trace:    

Timestamp 2015/08/21 14:02:39:130363000130363000
dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace:
ORA-06512: at "OMS.FOLDER_PKG", line 2661
ORA-06512: at "OMS.DOC_LOG_STEP_PKG", line 2436
dbms_utility.format_error_stack:
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

Comment: I think this question will find a better home at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh ya.... how do I move it?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way for you to fast-track it but I voted to close this question as off-tic and specifying that it should be migrated to dba.stackexchange.com.  With enough votes, it should just happen, I think.

Comment: I created it on dba.se...com    thx

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111971/can-a-table-lock-eliminate-a-deadlock-or-make-it-worse-oracle

Comment: Might adding explicit table locks mitigate a deadlock problem?  Possible, I guess.  Might it make the problem worse?  Sure.  Might it do nothing?  Absolutely.  Rather than speculating, though, was does the deadlock trace file tell you is the actual source of the deadlock?  What is the issue that causes your application to generate that deadlock?